# Global vs User Windows Environment Variables

Tags: windows, environment-variables

I need to understand how Global vs User variables works in windows.

**Case 1:**
If the same variable is defined at *user* and *global* section what is the behaviour? E.g. I have defined a %PATH% variable either in *user* and *global* sections and I see only *global* value; is there a way to 'append" *user* PATH to *global* PATH?

**Case 2:**
The variables defined in *user* section are not 'resolved' in *global* section. If I use `SET` command I see a list of all defined variables (*user* and *global*) but 'cross references' are not resolved.

**E.g.**

in user section I define:

```
VAR1=test-user
```

in global section I define:

```
VAR2=%VAR1%-more;%VAR3%-more
VAR3=test-global
```

with `SET` I see:

```
...
VAR1=test-user
VAR2=%VAR1%-more;test-global-more
VAR3=test-global
...
```

I'm on a Windows 7 x64 box.

So, based on the tests above, my conclusions are:

- global variables override user variables (if the name is the same only global is valid)
- no cross reference is admitted between user and global variables

Am I right?

Comment: Can I assume you're writing a batch file?

Comment: @martineau What I wrote above are my tests. I suppose a behaviour that I added in an update to my question, but I don't know if that's a correct interpretation of my tests.

Comment: @Dave no, I'm configuring windows manually thorugh 'control panel > system and security > system' and then restarting a CMD session at every change.

Comment: To answer part of question, I'm pretty sure that user vars can reference system vars.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your conclusions aren't quite right, at least according to my testing.

- User variables can reference system (global) ones.

  System variables cannot reference user variables.
- User variables will override system (global) ones.

  Just in the default set, `TEMP` (and `TMP`) are defined as the user variable as `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp` and at the same time as the system variable as `C:\Windows\TEMP`.

  `PATH` appears to be a special case, where the user variable `PATH` (if defined) is always appended to the system variable rather than overriding it.

Comment: My tests confirm all but one thing: user's PATH is not appended to global's PATH, but overrided by it. In my configuration they're written in different case: it matters?

Comment: @AndreaColleoni Case should not matter. If I create a user variable named `PATH` (or `path`) with the value `C:\test`, save (press `OK`), open a *new* command prompt and type `echo %path%`, `C:\test` appears on the end.

Comment: I've done as you said. I've also renamed user's PATH to USER_PATH and saw that global's PATH is automatically prepended to USER_PATH. If I leave the two named PATH I see only PATH's global value.

Comment: @AndreaColleoni `USER_PATH` has no special meaning for me. Your system may be different from mine for whatever reason... Could someone elase try & confirm it one way or the other?