# How to set user environment variables in Windows Server 2008 R2 as a normal user?

Tags: environment-variables, path, windows-server-2012

**Edit**
This is a duplicate of a question, however not the one identified. It is a duplicate of [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/458554/global-vs-user-windows-environment-variables?rq=1).

I am remotely logged into an instance of Windows Server 2012 as a regular user. I can't get administrative privileges. I have opened the environment variables control from control panel. The Path variable apparently can only be changed by the administrator. How do I modify the Path variable to include C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE?

[image]

Comment: The path is in two parts. You can change the `user` part of the path variable.

Comment: Do not cross-post. This is not a programming question, so the SO question should be closed/deleted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows Server 2008 R2 Environment Variables](https://superuser.com/questions/178008/windows-server-2008-r2-environment-variables).  While the duplicate is with regards to Windows Server 2008 R2, the answer is still applicable to Windows Server 2012, since given the constraints only the user variable can be changed.  It should only be necessary to modify the system Path variable if the application is being run as a different user while logged into another user.

Comment: The command prompt allows you to set Global (requiring admin rights) variables using SET, or User (not requiring admin rights) variables using the SETX command: https://superuser.com/questions/341192/how-can-i-display-the-contents-of-an-environment-variable-from-the-command-promp/832962#832962

Comment: @Ramhound I don't believe that user-session variables can be set that way.

Comment: @music2myear - The screenshot clearly shows that the Edit button is enabled for the user Path variable.  If modified to include the desired path would update the Path variable for the user.  Although I will admit, my duplicate choice wasn't the best (first relevant link).  [This](https://superuser.com/questions/458554/global-vs-user-windows-environment-variables?rq=1) would be my second choice.

Comment: @music2myear Your second choice is much more relevant to my question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Global vs User Windows Environment Variables](https://superuser.com/questions/458554/global-vs-user-windows-environment-variables)